# Pytube. Как узнать количество лайков и дизлайков?

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

Как можно узнать используя pytube или другими инструментами количество лайков и дизлайков если таковые имеются?

Comment: используйте Google data api

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться `YouTube Data API`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


API_KEY = ''  # Подставьте свой!


params = {
    'part': 'statistics',
    'id': 'PpTqzVGPLQY',
    'key': API_KEY,
}
d = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', params=params).json()
statistics = d['items'][0]['statistics']

likes = statistics['likeCount']
dislikes = statistics['dislikeCount']
print(f'{likes} / {dislikes}')
```

***stdout:***

```py
114 / 4
```